# Datastore Mobile Writes

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

In the google App Engine usage history, I just noticed the field "Datastore Mobile Writes". This is in addition of the usual "Datastore Writes", does anyone have any information on what this is? There's also "Datastore Mobile Reads" and "Small Datastore Mobile Operations".

> Datastore Mobile Writes
>   $0.60/Million Ops 0.00    0.05    0.00    $0.00

Comment: Hi, did you found out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It was a test SKU that was published, but not wired up to anything.